# Transform code from member function to non member function

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class family
{
private:
    double weight;
    double height;
public:
    family(double x,double y); 
    ~family();
    double getWeight();
    double getHeight();
    double setWeight();
    double setHeight();
    bool operator==(const family &)const; 
};

bool family::operator ==(const family &b)const
{
         return weight==b.weight;
}     

family::family(double x, double y)
{
    weight = x;
    height = y;
}

double family::getWeight()
{
    return weight;
}

double family::getHeight()
{
    return height;
}

family::~family(){}

int main()
{
 family a(70.0,175.2);
 family b(68.5,178.2);

 if(a==b)
 cout << "A is bigger than B" << endl;
 else
 cout << "A is smaller than B" << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Above the code, I can implement operator overloading with member function. However, I failed to implement operator overloading with non member function. How should i modify this code b.b
Please help me..

Comment: Better show the relevant code and remove the irrelevant one.

Comment: where's the code for the failed attempt?

Comment: don't compare `double`'s with `==` in `return weight==b.weight;`

Comment: Did you mean something like `friend  bool operator==(const family &,const family &);`?

Comment: Why `if(a==b)` then `A is bigger than B`?

Comment: I have no failed attempt. I just wonder another method for implementing the operator overloading. For example, in public member, friend Vector operator+(const Vector& v1, const Vector& v2); // It is declaration. (Non class member function)--> Vector operator+(const Vector& v1, const Vector& v2){ ~~ }. This code can be compiled. However, its return type is class against above code.. therefore i need your help guys bb

Comment: (To Anton Savin) It is just sample for practice. There is no reason why i named like that code. The words is not important.

Comment: bool operator==(family& a,family& b)
{
        return a.getWeight()==b.getWeight();
} When i try this code, it can be compiled and succeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the only difference between a member function and a non-member function is that it's passed an implicit `this` pointer as well as any other arguments and it has access to `private/protected` members.  So to transform *any* member function to a non-member function is to simply factor it out of the `class` definition. make it a `friend` of that class and add a parameter that's a reference to that class.  Pass in an object of that class when you call it.  You can also do a `const&` of the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
class family
{
private:
    double weight;
    double height;
public:
    family( double x, double y );
    ~family( );

    // getters should be const
    double getWeight( ) const;
    double getHeight( ) const;
    double setWeight( );
    double setHeight( );
};
// no reason to make it friend of class
// b/c it does not work with private/protected members 
bool operator==( const family & first, const family & second );

// better to move into cpp file
bool operator==( const family & first, const family & second )
{
    return first.getWeight( ) == second.getWeight( );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Friend Function and use  objects as parameter of that function like we use in << operator.
we also can use operator without friend function :

```
bool operator==(const family first, const family second) 
{
if(first.getWeight( ) == second.getWeight( )){
return True;
else
 return False;
}
```